# RedShift Error when using COUNT (Distinct XXX) ERROR: XX000: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aginity

I have a small query running in RedShift through Aginity that is getting the following error:

> ERROR: XX000: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error

Current Query:

```
SELECT 'MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.FIELDA' as obj_name,
COUNT(*) as rows, 
COUNT(DISTINCT FIELDA) as distinct_vals, 
SUM(CASE WHEN FIELDA in ('00DK','00DC','00DE','00DD','00DB') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as enter, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(FIELDA) IN ('',null) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nulls 
FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
```

However if i remove the DISTINCT it runs:

```
SELECT 'MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.FIELDA' as obj_name,
COUNT(*) as rows, 
COUNT(FIELDA) as distinct_vals, 
SUM(CASE WHEN FIELDA in ('00DK','00DC','00DE','00DD','00DB') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as enter, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(FIELDA) IN ('',null) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nulls 
FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
```

Comment: Apologies for the PostgreSQL Tag, i assumed it was relevant due to Redshift being based around PostgreSQl ~8.3?

Comment: is MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE a view by any chance?

Comment: @JonScott It is

Comment: you need to share the sql for the view (ie update your question) as that is the root cause - in effect you are running that sql (in the view) as a subquery. you have broken one of the circumstances documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html. However it looks like the answer below solved your issue anyway.

Comment: I have got it working from the answer but i will take a look at that documentation, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you use window functions in a subquery?

```
SELECT 'MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.FIELDA' as obj_name,
       COUNT(*) as rows, 
       SUM( (seqnum = 1)::INT ) as distinct_vals, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN FIELDA in ('00DK','00DC','00DE','00DD','00DB') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as enter, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(FIELDA) IN ('',null) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nulls 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FIELDA ORDER BY FIELDA) as seqnum
      FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE t
     ) t
```